# grails 3 plugin installation location

Tags: grails, gradle, build.gradle, grails-plugin, grails-3.0

Grails 3 installed a plugin somewhere (and ran it) after the plugin was listed in `build.gradle`. The plugin name is `org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3`.

It is a mystery to me where it was installed on disk. Some sources point me to .m2 maven repository but it does not seem to be there. Where should I look for it?

Comment: The location varies for each OS. If you are using Windows, you might want to look in **C:\Users\<user-profile-name>\.grails\ivy-cache**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your home (`~`) directory under `.gradle/caches` directory.

Full path: `~/.gradle/caches`

Comment: indeed found one under .gradle/caches/modules-2 on mac os

Comment: When you are running app there's a file called .dependencies in your applications build -directory where is all the dependencies listed.